# Filter DataFrame based on dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to filter pandas dataframe with values form `dictionary`.

Here is explanation.

Let's say I have `dataframe` like this. Data types are only `string` , `int` and `timestamps`.

```
+---------+-------+------+-------+-----------------+
|  Title  | Type  | Size | Price |      Date       |
+---------+-------+------+-------+-----------------+
| title 1 | red   |   10 |    20 | 4.9.2020. 13:21 |
| title 2 | blue  |   20 |    40 | 4.9.2020. 11:21 |
| title 3 | green |   15 |    50 | 4.5.2020. 13:21 |
+---------+-------+------+-------+-----------------+
```

and I have dictionary created from users input which looks like this:

```
  userDict =  {'Title':'title 1', 'Type':'red','Size':[10,15],'Price':[40, 80], 
    'Date':[Timestamp('2020-04-09 13:21:00'), Timestamp('2020-04-09 14:21:00')]}
```

`'Price': [50, 80]` would mean that user is requesting all prices between 50 and 80.

How can I get filtered pandas dataframe based on values from dictionary?

Original dataframe has many other columns. Besides `Title` and `Type` I could have many other `string` columns, and besides `Size` and `Price` I could also have many other `int` columns.

So dictionary can be much larger containing filtering requests for many other fields.

**My solution so far:**

```
for key, value in userDict.items():
    if 'list' in str(type(value)):
        filteredDF= originalDF[(originalDF[key] > value[0]) & (originalDF[key] < value[1])]
    if 'str' in str(type(value)):
        filteredDF= filteredDF[filteredDF[key].str.contains(value, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

But it keeps returning original dataframe.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

extract price value like below,

```
start, end = userDict["Price"]
```

then filter from main dataframe like below

```
res = df[df["Price"],between(start, end)]
```

Comment: Idea is to iterate over all int, string and date fields. I know how to filter by them individualy.